# Laravel mix with prompt questions

Tags: node.js, laravel, laravel-mix

I want to add a few prompt questions in Laravel Mix and do its' jobs based on the developer answers.

But with the below code, the Laravel Mix process doesn't stop and ask the given prompt questions. Instead, it skips the prompt questions and shows a message `Compiled successfully in 34ms.`

I add the following code in the `webpack.mix.js` file.

```js
const { stdin, stdout } = process;

// Prompt function
function prompt(question) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    stdin.resume();
    stdout.write(question);

    stdin.on('data', data => resolve(data.toString().trim()));
    stdin.on('error', err => reject(err));
  });
}

// Init
async function promptQuestions() {
    try {
        
      let compile_script = await prompt('Would you like to compile scripts only?[y/n]')
      
      let copy_theme     = await prompt('Would you like to copy theme folders? [y/n]')

         const answers = { compile_script, copy_theme };

          /*
          | Run laravel Mix Here based on the 'answers' obj
          / -------------------------------------------------- */

      stdin.pause();

    } catch(error) {
      console.log("There's an error!");
      console.log(error);
    }
    process.exit();
}

promptQuestions()
```

Comment: I have never heard or see this, where did you see that this is possible ? I think this is not, and the only way is to create a custom script like `npm run compile` or anything similar where it runs a custom JS and you do inside it what you want...

Comment: If you're using Laravel, you could use [Laravel Envoy](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/envoy) to execute tasks. It allows for prompts and is simple and straightforward to use. I typically run NPM inside it.